# Use different collections in mongodb depending on item type

Tags: mongodb, scrapy

I am crawling and scraping websites with [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) and saving the items to [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) using the item pipeline from [scrapy-mongodb](https://github.com/sebdah/scrapy-mongodb). Doing this how can I save items of different types to different collections? Like e.g. items of type `PersonItem` to collection `persons` and items of type `BookItem` to collection `books`? If this is not possible using the item pipeline can you think of another solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create two different pipeline for each type:
in the `pipelines.py`:

```
class PersonPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_PERSON_COLLECTION']] # use the person collection

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if not isinstance(item,PersonItem):
            return item # return the item to let other pipeline to handle it
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))

class BookPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_BOOK_COLLECTION']] # use the book collection

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if not isinstance(item,PersonItem):
            return item # return the item to let other pipeline to handle it
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
```

in the `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = { # declare the handle sequence
    'myproject.pipelines.PersonPipeline':100,
    'myproject.pipelines.BookPipeline':200,
}
MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = "MyDB" # db name
MONGODB_PLACE_COLLECTION = "persons" # collection name
MONGODB_LIST_COLLECTION = "books"
```

When a item is return , the `PersonPipeline` will first handle it. If the item is not `PersonItem` type, then it will be returned to the next pipeline, which is the `BookPipeline` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible in a (subclassed) `MongoDBPipeline` pipeline.

The following is NOT tested but one option is to change `self.collection` to a dict of collections, mapping an item type to a Mongo collection.

```
class CustomMongoDBPipeleine(MongoDBPipeline):

  def __init__(self, settings):
    ...
    mapping = {
        PersonItem: 'persons',
        BookItem: 'books',
    }
    self.collection = {}
    for itype, collection_name in mapping.items():
        self.collection[itype] = database[collection_name]
```

The mapping could come from the configuration, and use item type class names instead of item classes directly.

And use something like:

```
    insert_item(self, item, spider):
        ...
        self.collection.get(type(item)).insert(item, continue_on_error=True)
        ...
```